# Sublime Text 2, can't indent double quoted strings in python

Tags: string, sublimetext2, indentation, double-quotes

While editing Python code, if I have a double quoted String on a single line, for example:

```
 my_var = [
 "string1",
 "string2"
]
```

and I try to indent `"string1"` with the TAB key, it doesn't indent it, but instead it get the cursor inside the quotes.
This does **NOT happen** if I use single quotes.

To investigate I put this in the console:

```
sublime.log_commands(True)
```

And whenever I try to perform the previous action I get:

```
command: move {"by": "characters", "forward": true}
```

I suppose it is the right command but there's something in the way that prevents to be executed. Any clue?

Comment: what commmand comes up if you try to tab-indent the line with `myvar` on it?

Comment: @MattDMo this is the outcome `command: insert_best_completion {"default": " ", "exact": false}`